# Tkinter window staying on top

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I haven't added any TopLevel or any attributes as such to make the python application stay at the front, however, the app does stay at the front and new windows will stay behind the main window. Does anyone have any fixes for this please?
Thanks in advance

window code:

```
 root = tkinter.Tk()
    window_title = "Teacher - {}".format(current_teacher.name)

    window_img = PhotoImage(file="images/window_img.png")
    root.iconphoto(False, window_img)

    root.title(window_title)
    root.geometry('800x450')
    root['bg'] = blue
```

new window code:

```
        calendar_window = tkinter.Tk()
```

Comment: Try adding `calendar_window.focus_set()` or `calendar_window.focus_force()`

Comment: This didn't seem to work, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Can you please show us a minimal working example where we can try things out?

Comment: I've made a working example. If it doesn't work then the problem is probably the image loading part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

This should force `tk` `calendar_window` to the front.

A slight change thanks to a suggestion by @TheLizzard.

```py
import tkinter as tk

master = tk.Tk()
master.config( padx = 4, pady = 4)
master.title("Demo")
master.geometry("300x200")

calendar_window = tk.Tk()
calendar_window.title("Second Window")
calendar_window.geometry("300x200")

calendar_window.after(100, calendar_window.lift)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not `calendar_window.after(100, calendar_window.lift)`?

Comment: Yeah, that's an alternative.

Comment: This didn't seem to work, thanks for the suggestion!